# Proving that Injectivity of a Linear Map is equivalent to Ker(f) = {0}

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, the following is the theorem I'm trying to prove.

Let $f:V \to W$ be a linear map. Then, $f$ is injective iff $Ker(f) = \{0\}$.

---

My Proof Attempt:

Let $f: V \to W$ be an injective linear map. Then, we have to show that $Ker(f) = \{0\}$. Clearly, $\{0\} \subset Ker(f)$ since $Ker(f)$ is a subspace of $V$. So, we have to simply show that $Ker(f) \subset \{0\}$.

Let $v \in Ker(f)$. Then, $f(v) = 0$. Now, either $v = 0$ or $v \neq 0$.

If $v = 0$, then we're done. This proves that $Ker(f) = \{0\}$.

If $v \neq 0$, then $f(v) = 0 = f(0)$. So:

$f(v) = f(0) \implies v = 0$

That is a contradiction. Hence, $v = 0$ and $Ker(f) = \{0\}$.

Now, let $Ker(f) = \{0\}$. Then, we have to show that $f$ is injective. Let $x,y \in V$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. Then:

$f(x) = f(y) \implies f(x)-f(y) = 0 \implies f(x-y) = 0 \implies x-y \in Ker(f)$

Hence, $x-y = 0$ and that proves that $x = y$. That is exactly the condition for injectivity and it proves the desired result.

Can someone look through the argument above and tell me if it is correct or not? Also, I would want to hear any sort of criticism on the quality of my proof-writing.

Comment: For the implication, by injectivity of $f$, if $v\in \ker(f)$, $$f(v)=0=f(0)\implies v=0.$$

Comment: Oof yea bad habit, I have a tendency of leaving things out like that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does $\ker(T) = \{0\} \Leftrightarrow T$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164333/why-does-kert-0-leftrightarrow-t-is-injective)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2193333/721644

Comment: While that is a very helpful link and I'll certainly look at the answers there for additional insights, that doesn't answer my question because it's not directly addressing the standard of my proof or the correctness of my proof. I generally don't refer to model answers until I have given my best shot at proving a given theorem.

Comment: However, I'll still upvote your comment because of the effort you put in to lead me to a rich source of additional insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct, but for example the contradiction part is not necessary. If $f(v) = 0$, then you can automatically conclude that $v=0$ since $f(0)=0$ by any linear map and thus by injectivity $v=0$.

Here is how I would write down the proof:

Assume $f$ is injective. Then

$$v \in \ker f \implies f(v) = 0 = f(0) \implies v = 0$$

and thus $\ker f = \{0\}$.

Conversely, assume that $\ker f = \{0\}$ and assume that $f(x) = f(y)$ for $x,y \in V$. Then
$$0 = f(x)-f(y) = f(x-y) \implies x-y \in \ker f = \{0\}\implies x-y = 0 \implies x = y$$

demonstrating injectivity. $\quad \square$

Comment: Oooh that's really nice. Damn it, I have a bad habit of making my arguments unnecessarily long. I don't really know how to stop that from happening other than just practising and writing more proofs.

Comment: This is normal for beginners! Don't worry, your proof was fine but just could be made a litte shorter. I would have given full credit if I graded you (I'm not an instructor, however), so well done!

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just hoping that this will become less of a problem over time.

Comment: It will! Just keep practising!